# Can python multiprocessing work on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-multiprocessing

I can't manage to make multiprocessing (not talking about multithreading) work on a google cloud function. Like a simple map operation like this:

```
with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(do_work, inputs)
```

Maybe it just isn't possible on cloud functions?

When I try it my function just stops before the multiprocessing part and timeouts.
No error message or anything.
I don't find anything about this in the docs.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have to send the HTTP response only when the multiprocessing is over. If the multiprocessing  run AFTER the response, the CPU is throttled and you wan't perform processing.

Comment: Yeah sure but that's already what I am doing. The multiprocessing is contained with the `with Pool()`, and I am trying to use `results` object after that to build my HTTP response

Comment: It should be possible. But not sure with Cloud Functions gen1. Try gen2!